# How to write vertically in a cell

Tags: tables, rotating

I know that with `\begin{sideways} ... \end{sideways}` I can write a text vertically, but it rotates the text by +90 degrees. What should I do to rotate it by -90 degrees?

Comment: Does `\begin{turn}{-90}` or `\begin{turn}{270}` work?

Comment: So, what's the best option of all these alternatives?

Answer (score 25):

You could use the environment `turn`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sideways}Test\end{sideways}

\begin{turn}{-90}Test 90\end{turn}

\begin{turn}{270}Test 270\end{turn}

\hrule

Tabular:

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Normal
&
\begin{turn}{-90}Test 90\end{turn}
&
\begin{turn}{270}Test 270\end{turn}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result (extract)]

Comment: now, how we are going to center the text here ? tried everything and it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal Working Example and create a question? How do you want to center the text?

Comment: It is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326897/vertical-alignment-of-a-turned-cell

Answer (score 1):

The example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table) worked for me for rotating and make it aligned with the column.

```
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{4{*}{yourtexthere}}}
```

Edit:
The complete executable code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Multicolumn table}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{tabular}{
  |p{\dimexpr.05\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 1
  |p{\dimexpr.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}% column 2
  |p{\dimexpr.75\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.3333\arrayrulewidth}|% column 3
  }
  \hline
  \centering \textbf{}     & \raggedright \textbf{col2}     & \raggedright\arraybackslash \textbf{col3}    \\ \hline 
  \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{TB}}}
&
val1.
&
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `\reflectbox` command from the `graphics` package. If you provide a Minimal Working Example, someone might be able to help with the specifics.

Comment: If you're using `graphics` commands (and there's no reason not to) you might as well just use `\rotatebox`