# How to rotate text in multirow table?

Tags: tables, boxes, rotating, multirow

I have a big table with a problem, when I want to rotate the text in a `\multirow` cell, the text is placed outside and is bigger than the dimensions of the cell, I took some advice from here, using`\parbox`, and then `\rotatebox`. But I don't get good results.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{text}\\
 \hline
 \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{rota}}} & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image: rotate problem]

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Put `\rotatebox` inside like:

```
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}}}
```

## Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{text}\\
 \hline
 \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}}} & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

I have eliminated some spurious vertical lines in the title and introduced the origin for rotation. However, the idea of introducing a `parbox` did not get in to my head as this may not be needed for the present MWE. In case you have other uses in your actual code, you may use the alignment specifiers to `parbox` (Here `[t]`).

Comment: If `rota` is instead `rotatoata`, it will be outside the table. Any idea of how to force it to increase the spacing of rows or something to avoid this?

Comment: @J.C.Leitão You can't. Only way is to increase the number of rows from `3` to `4` or more.

Comment: For posterity, an hacky solution is to decrease the text-size.

Comment: Note that *with colors* it is safer to use the last row to contain the `multirow`, see this [blog](http://texblog.org/2014/05/19/coloring-multi-row-tables-in-latex/)

Comment: I can confirm that \parbox does not seem necessary

Answer (score 24):

A variant that doesn't require manual adjustment of width and automatically centers the rotated cell horizontally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\STAB}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{text} \\ \hline
     \multirow{3}{*}{\STAB{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}}}
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\
     & text                      &                           &                           &                           &                           \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to work without `STAB` too for me: `\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}}`. Not sure what it is for.

Answer (score 11):

Improving Harish Kumar's answer on follow up question of placing longer word inside a cell, i.e., `rota` to `rotatoata`. It also uses `\rotatebox` and `\parbox` but the order is different.

And, if the intentions of using `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text}` is to center the text, then  `{\hfill Text\hfill}` could be alternative solution.

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}\hline
~ & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & {\hfill Text\hfill} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\centering rotato-ata}}} & text &&&&\\
& text &testing A& testing B&&\\
& text &right aligned&&&\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Updated the package from graphics to graphicx and it works. Checked with Overleaf.

Answer (score 5):

add `\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}` before `\begin{document}`

and then just do `\rot{Whatever you want to rotate}`

Hope it helps..

Found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98439/73321)

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` and its built-in command `\Block`, you have directly the expected output.

Morever, with that command `\Block`, you specify the number of *logical* rows and not the number of physical row (as with `\multirow`).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}

 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[!h]
   \centering
   \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
     \hline
      & Text & Text & Text & Text & text \\ \hline
      \Block{3-1}<\rotate>{rota}
      & text & & & & \\
      & text & & & & \\
      & text & & & & \\ \hline
   \end{NiceTabular}
 \end{table} 
 \end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]