# Create a table with merged cells and vertical text

Tags: tables

I would like to create a table like [image]

Currently, I was reading this thread [How to rotate text in multirow table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table) but I don't get how to do it as above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a start. Hope it helps. Updated as recommended by @WojciechMorawiec.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{label01} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{label02}                                             \\ \hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some text}}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{item 1}} & description & description \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & description & description \\ \cline{2-4} 
                             & \multirow{2}{*}{item 2}                       & description & description \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & description & description \\ \hline
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some text}}}   & \multirow{2}{*}{item 1}                       & description & description \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & description & description \\ \cline{2-4} 
                             & \multirow{2}{*}{item 2}                       & description & description \\ \cline{3-4} 
                             &                                               & description & description \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Moving the separator from the right to the left 'label'-multicolumn fixes the small glitch for me:
`\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{label01} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{label02}`

Comment: @WojciechMorawiec updated answer.

Comment: @BerthinTorres Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
label01 & \Block{1-3}{label02} \\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate some text} & \Block{2-1}{item 1} & description & description \\
                               &                     & description & description \\
                               & \Block{2-1}{item 1} & description & description \\
                               &                     & description & description \\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate some text} & \Block{2-1}{item 1} & description & description \\
                               &                     & description & description \\
                               & \Block{2-1}{item 1} & description & description \\
                               &                     & description & description \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]