# Creating a table with merged cells in RevTex 4.2 template

Tags: tables, formatting, revtex

I'm trying to create a table that looks like this:

[image]

I'm using the [RevTex 4.2 Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/revtex-4-dot-2-template-and-sample/yydsrzvrqrzs). I've been reading [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150637/create-a-table-with-merged-cells-and-vertical-text) but am a beginner with Latex and am not sure how to modify it to make the table I want.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // May I suggest this read for you? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX . Once you've some more basic knowledge about Latex, things will become easier for you. At the moment, you've chosen a task too much, in my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{width=0.8\linewidth,
            hlines=0.4pt, vlines=0.4pt,
            colspec = {l *{5}{X[c,m]}},
             colsep = 4pt,
             row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt
            }
Assumption  &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Double slit  
                        &   & Right slit    & Left slit \\
$a=\#$ mm   & \SetCell[r=2]{c} $\lambda$ [nm] = 
                & \#    & \SetCell[r=2]{c} \#   
                            & \#            & \#        \\
$d=\#$ mm   &   & \#    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} n/a  
                                            &           \\
$\lambda = \#$ mm 
            & $a$ [mm] =& \SetCell[c=2]{c} n/a
                            &   & \#        & \#        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works well, too.

Comment: @JaquelineBernard, now you can select the answer which solve your problem on the best way ... and accept it (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccwc{1cm}wc{1cm}cc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
\RowStyle[bold]{}
Assumption & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Double slit} & Right slit & Left slit \\
$a=\#$ mm & \Block{2-1}{$\lambda$ [nm] = } & \# & \Block{2-1}{\#} & \# & \# \\
$d=\#$ mm &                          & \# &                 & \Block{1-2}{n/a} \\
$\lambda = \#$ mm & $a$ [mm] = & \Block{1-2}{\#} & & \# & \# 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you! That worked well. The only problem is I'm getting an error with the line \RowStyle[bold]{}: "Package nicematrix Error: As for now, there is only three keys available." But this isn't a big problem since I can use \textbf{ } for the column titles.

Comment: I think that you have not the latest version of `nicematrix`.

Comment: How can I get the latest version? I'm using Overleaf.

Comment: Overleaf has not the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Ok thanks! @F. Pantigny