# Sideways in table

Tags: tables, rotating

I created this table:

[image]

with this code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{L*{2}C}
        \toprule
    Propriedade & Equipamento & Norma \\
         \midrule
    Estruturais: & & \\
    Gramagem & Mettler HK 160 & ISO 536 \\
    Espessura & Micrómetro SE 051 D2 & ISO 534 \\
    Índice de Mão & Calculado & ISO 534 \\
    Resistência ao Ar & Gurley SE 121 & ISO 5636-5 \\
    Rugosidade de Bendtsen & L\&W Bendtsen & ISO 8791-2 \\
    Ópticas: & & \\
    Brancura & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2470 \\
    Opacidade & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2471 \\
    Coeficiente Específico de Dispersão da Luz (CEDL) & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 9416 \\
    Mecânicas: & & \\
    Rebentamento & Burst-o-matic & ISO 2758 \\
    Resistência à tracção & Alwetron TH1 & ISO 1924-2 \\
    Resistência ao Rasgamento &  Elmendorf 125 & ISO 1974 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
      \label{equipamentos_folhas}
    \end{table}
```

But, I want to insert text in sideways, like this table:

[image]

The words: Mechanical, optical and structural.

How I can put this in my table ?

I has already put in my table, but first column should be more little :S
My recently table:

[image]

My new code:

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{CL*{3}C}
    \toprule
& Propriedade & Equipamento & Norma & Unidade \\
     \midrule
\parbox[t]{10cm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}}} & Gramagem & Mettler HK 160 & ISO 536 & $g.m^{-2}$ \\
&Espessura & Micrómetro SE 051 D2 & ISO 534 & m \\
&Índice de Mão & Calculado & ISO 534 & $cm^{3}.g$ \\
&Resistência ao Ar & Gurley SE 121 & ISO 5636-5 & $s.100ml^{-1}$ \\
&Rugosidade de Bendtsen & L\&W Bendtsen & ISO 8791-2 & $ml.min^{-1}$ \\
&&&&\\
\parbox[t]{10cm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}}}  & Brancura & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2470 & \% \\
& Opacidade & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2471 & \% \\
& CEDL & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 9416 & $m^2.kg^{-1}$ \\
&&&&\\
\parbox[t]{10cm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}}}& Resistência ao Rebentamento & Burst-o-matic & ISO 2758 & KPa \\
& Resistência à Tracção & Alwetron TH1 & ISO 1924-2 & $N.m^{-1}$ \\
& Resistência ao Rasgamento &  Elmendorf 125 & ISO 1974 & $m.N^{-1}$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{equipamentos_folhas}
\end{table}
```

thank you

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table helps.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I has already changed

Comment: Please post a **complete** small document illustrating the problem. This should include everything needed to compile. Complete code is much more useful than mere fragments which leave readers to guess which packages are necessary to compile, which class you are using, and to a document framework of their own.

Answer (score 3):

A solution with only one X-type column (actually L) and units typeset with the `siunitx` package. I also load the  `makecell` package to improve vertical spacing, and the `caption` package to have better vertical spacing between the table caption and the table body and suppress the `:` if there is no caption text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}%
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering%
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cLclc@{}}
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-5}
& Propriedade & Equipamento & Norma & Unidade \\
     \cmidrule{2-5}
& Gramagem & Mettler HK 160 & ISO 536 & \si{\g·\m⁻²}\\
 & Espessura & Micrómetro SE 051 D2 & ISO 534 & m\\
 & Índice de Mão & Calculado & ISO 534 & \si{cm⁻³·g }\\
 & Resistência ao Ar & Gurley SE 121 & ISO 5636-5 & \si{s·100\ml⁻¹ }\\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Estruturais}} & Rugosidade de Bendtsen & L\&W Bendtsen & ISO 8791-2 & \si{\ml·\minute⁻¹ } \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Ópticas}} & Brancura & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2470 & \% \\
 & Opacidade & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2471 & \% \\
 & \makecell{Coeficiente Específico de Dispersão\\ da Luz (CEDL)} & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 9416 & \si{\m²·\kg⁻¹} \\
\addlinespace
& Rebentamento & Burst-o-matic & ISO 2758 & \si{\K\Pa}\\
& Resistência à tracção & Alwetron TH1 & ISO 1924-2 & \si{N·\m⁻¹}\\
\multirow{-4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin =c]{90}{Mecânicas}} & Resistência ao Rasgamento & Elmendorf 125 & ISO 1974 & \si{\m·\N⁻¹}\\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-5}
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{equipamentos_folhas}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `\parbox` as you have only one word in the first column. Further you can use the second (optional) argument of `\multirow` to adjust the vertical placement like:

```
\multirow{5}[10]{*}....
```

Adjust it appropriately. Further, the first column can be of `c` type.

Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx,tabularx,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
 \begin{document}     
    \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cL*{3}C}
    \toprule
& Propriedade & Equipamento & Norma & Unidade \\
     \midrule
\multirow{5}[14]{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & Gramagem & Mettler HK 160 & ISO 536 & $g.m^{-2}$ \\
&Espessura & Micrómetro SE 051 D2 & ISO 534 & m \\
&Índice de Mão & Calculado & ISO 534 & $cm^{3}.g$ \\
&Resistência ao Ar & Gurley SE 121 & ISO 5636-5 & $s.100ml^{-1}$ \\
&Rugosidade de Bendtsen & L\&W Bendtsen & ISO 8791-2 & $ml.min^{-1}$ \\
&&&&\\
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}}  & Brancura & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2470 & \% \\
& Opacidade & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 2471 & \% \\
& CEDL & L\&W Elrepho & ISO 9416 & $m^2.kg^{-1}$ \\
&&&&\\
\multirow{5}[5]{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}}& Resistência ao Rebentamento & Burst-o-matic & ISO 2758 & KPa \\
& Resistência à Tracção & Alwetron TH1 & ISO 1924-2 & $N.m^{-1}$ \\
& Resistência ao Rasgamento &  Elmendorf 125 & ISO 1974 & $m.N^{-1}$ \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \label{equipamentos_folhas}
\end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]