# Creating a table with axes

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a LaTeX version of the table pictured below. This is mainly complicated by the axes below and to the right. The code given below is how far I've managed to come. First of all I am not too happy with how it looks (I'd prefer it to be a bit more like the picture) and second of all I cannot figure out how to get these axes done.

I have no idea how long it'd take any of you guys to give me a hand, but I am on a very tight schedule here, so any help would be highly appreciated!

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{table}[h]
\tiny
\centering
\caption{Framework for health care planning and control \citep{hans2012framework}.}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{ XXXXX } & \textbf{Medical Planning} & \textbf{Resource capacity planning} & \textbf{Materials planning} & \textbf{Financial planning}\\
\hline
\textbf{Strategic}  & Research, development of medical protocols & Case mix planning, capacity dimensioning, workforce planning & Supply chain and warehouse design & Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies \\
\hline
\textbf{Tactical}   & Treatment selection, protocol selection & Block planning, staffing, admission planning & Supplier selection, tendering & Budget and cost allocation\\
\hline
\textbf{Offline Operational}   & Diagnosis and planning of an individual treatment & Appointment scheduling, workforce scheduling & Materials purchasing, determining order sizes & DRG billing, cash flow analysis\\
\hline
\textbf{Online Operational}  & Triage, diagnosing emergencies and complications & Monitoring, emergency coordination & Rush ordering, inventory replenishing & Billing complications and changes\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{t:framework}
\end{table}
```

[image: Framework overview]

Comment: I think it would be easier to use TikZ with the `matrix` library.

Comment: If you have gotten good answers to this and your other questions consider upvoting and/or accepting them. Accepting an answer marks the question as solved. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

**With Tikz Matrix**

You can use `Matrix` library  to create this tabular, in the code below we use three matrix

- `Matrix (T)` in the center which contain framed nodes.
- Two matrix in the top and left of `(T)`.

To create labels on the bottom and right of (T) with

```
\node[yshift=-2mm,font=\bfseries] at (T.south){$ \leftarrow $ managerial erea $ \rightarrow $};
```

and

```
\node[xshift=2mm,font=\large\bfseries,rotate=-90] at (T.east){$ \leftarrow $ \textbf{hierarchical decomposition} $ \rightarrow $};
```

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{Framework for health care planning and control.}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (T) [matrix of nodes,column sep=4pt,row sep=4pt,nodes={draw,text width=3.3cm,align=center,rounded corners,minimum height=1.3cm,inner sep=1pt,font=\footnotesize,anchor=south}]
{
 Research, development of medical protocols & Case mix planning, capacity dimensioning, workforce planning & Supply chain and warehouse design & Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies \\
 Treatment selection, protocol selection    & Block planning, staffing, admission planning & Supplier selection, tendering & Budget and cost allocation\\
 Diagnosis and planning of an individual treatment & Appointment scheduling, workforce scheduling & Materials purchasing, determining order sizes & DRG billing, cash flow analysis\\
 Triage, diagnosing emergencies and complications & Monitoring, emergency coordination & Rush ordering, inventory replenishing & Billing complications and changes\\                          
};

\node[yshift=-2mm,font=\bfseries] at (T.south){$ \leftarrow $ managerial erea $ \rightarrow $};

\node[xshift=2mm,font=\large\bfseries,rotate=-90] at (T.east){$ \leftarrow $ \textbf{hierarchical decomposition} $ \rightarrow $};


\matrix at (T.north west) [matrix of nodes,anchor=south west,yshift=-4mm,column sep=4pt,nodes={text width=3.3cm,align=center,minimum height=1.3cm,inner sep=1pt,font=\bfseries}]
{
Medical \par Planning & Resource \par capacity planning & Materials \par planning & Financial \par planning\\                           
};


\matrix at (T.north west) [matrix of nodes,anchor=north east,row sep=4pt,nodes={text width=2.3cm,align=right,minimum height=1.3cm,font=\bfseries}]
{
Strategic\\
Tactical\\
Offline \par Operational\\
Online \par Operational\\                          
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [Bibi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282446/creating-a-table-with-axes#comment680849_282446) suggested, the `matrix` library and `tikz` would probably be better suited, but just for adding the axes to the table I tweaked your code just a bit (basically adding a row and a column for each axis):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\tiny
\centering
\caption{Framework for health care planning and control}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{ XXXXXX } & \textbf{Medical Planning} & \textbf{Resource capacity planning} & \textbf{Materials planning} & \textbf{Financial planning}&\\\cline{1-5}
\textbf{Strategic}  & Research, development of medical protocols & Case mix planning, capacity dimensioning, workforce planning & Supply chain and warehouse design & Investment plans, contracting with insurance companies &\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{$ \leftarrow $ \textbf{hierarchical decomposition} $ \rightarrow $}}}\\\cline{1-5}
\textbf{Tactical}   & Treatment selection, protocol selection & Block planning, staffing, admission planning & Supplier selection, tendering & Budget and cost allocation&\\\cline{1-5}
\textbf{Offline Operational}   & Diagnosis and planning of an individual treatment & Appointment scheduling, workforce scheduling & Materials purchasing, determining order sizes & DRG billing, cash flow analysis&\\\cline{1-5}
\textbf{Online Operational}  & Triage, diagnosing emergencies and complications & Monitoring, emergency coordination & Rush ordering, inventory replenishing & Billing complications and changes&\\\cline{1-5}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{$ \leftarrow $ \textbf{managerial areas} $ \rightarrow $} &\\
\end{tabularx}
\label{t:framework}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The `parbox` trick to rotate the vertical axis comes from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89116/59615) answer by [Harish Kumar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11232/harish-kumar).