# How to use multirow?

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to create this table on latex

[image]

however I dont know how to use multi row.Here is my code

```
\begin{center}
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | }
 \hline 
   & & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ACTUAL}  \\ \hline
   &  &Class A & Class B  & Class C     \\ \hline
   &   Class A & 42 & 4 & 3     \\ \hline
  &   Class B & 11 & 35 & 2    \\ \hline
   &  Class C & 3 & 6 & 38    \\ \hline


    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix} 
\end{center}
```

And this what i get with the code

[image]

Note: and how can i center the value in table

Comment: For horizontal-centering, you need to use... centered columns! You can thus use `\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | c | c | c | }`. [How to rotate text in multirow table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89115/64454) might solve the *"Estimated"*-cell issue, right? And what about [no vertical lines](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
 \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | }
 \cline{3-5}
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{ACTUAL}  \\ \cline{3-5}
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} &Class A & Class B  & Class C     \\ \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\tiny ESTIMATED\,}} & Class A & 42 & 4 & 3\\ \cline{2-5}
  &   Class B & 11 & 35 & 2    \\ \cline{2-5}
   &  Class C & 3 & 6 & 38    \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{  l  l  c  c  c  }
            \toprule
            & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Actual}}  \\ 
            &  &Class A & Class B  & Class C     \\ 
            \midrule
            \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Estim.}}}}&   Class A & 42 & 4 & 3     \\ 
            &   Class B & 11 & 35 & 2    \\ 
            &  Class C & 3 & 6 & 38    \\ 
            \bottomrule

        \end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oops, didn't noticed Steven's answer before posting. moreover, this answer *does not* address what OP were asking... However, this is a suggestion for another (better ?) layout.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 variants, using `siunitx` for the centred-right aligned numbers, and different possible rules with `hhline, booktabs` and/or `boldline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, siunitx, boldline, hhline, booktabs}


 \begin{document}

\begin{center}
\centering\sisetup{table-format=2.0}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
 \begin{tabular}{c|l *{3}{V{0.3}S}|}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{ACTUAL} \\
  \hhline{~~|---}
   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & {Class A} & {Class B} & {Class C} \\
  \hhline{~|----|}%\clineB{3-5}{0.3}
  \multirow{3}{*}[-0.2ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize ESTIMATED\,}} & Class A & 42 & 4 & 3\\ \clineB{2-5}{0.3}
  & Class B & 11 & 35 & 2 \\ \clineB{2-5}{0.3}
   & Class C & 3 & 6 & 38 \\
   \hhline{~|----}
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\centering\sisetup{table-format=2.0}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
 \begin{tabular}{cl| *{3}{S}}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ACTUAL} \\
    & & {Class A} & {Class B} & {Class C} \\
 \cline{2-5}
  \multirow{3}{*}[-0.2ex]{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize ESTIMATED\,}} & Class A & 42 & 4 & 3\\ %
  & Class B & 11 & 35 & 2 \\ %
   & Class C & 3 & 6 & 38 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\centering\sisetup{table-format=2.0}
 \begin{tabular}{cl *{3}{S}}
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ACTUAL} \\
\cmidrule(l{-1.5em}r{-1.5em}){4-4}
    & & {Class A} & {Class B} & {Class C} \\%
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
    \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize ESTIMATED\,}} & Class A & 42 & 4 & 3\\ \addlinespace
  & Class B & 11 & 35 & 2 \\ \addlinespace
   & Class C & 3 & 6 & 38 \\
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-5}
\addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Risk Matrix}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. The key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the 'corners'. With the key `corners`, we have told nicematrix to take into consideration the corner north-west (NW).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\tiny}ccccc}[corners=NW,hvlines]
                               &         & \Block{1-3}{ACTUAL} \\
                               &         & Class A & Class B & Class C \\
\Block{3-1}{\rotate ESTIMATED} & Class A & 42      & 4       & 3       \\
                               & Class B & 11      & 35      & 2       \\
                               & Class C & 3       & 6       & 38 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]