# Rotate text in multirow table without specifying parbox size

Tags: rotating, multirow, parbox

I'm sorry for the extra question, but I'm not allowed to answer directly on [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table#89116). Is there a way to not specify the size of parboxes, but just choose cell size for this?

As a MWE, you can use the one mentioned under the initial topic:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
 \hline
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Text} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{text}\\
 \hline
 \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}}} & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 & text &&&&\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE has many errors ... use of `\parbox{...}` is wrong and also it is surplus. With use of the macro `\thead{...}` from package `makecell` you can simplified columns headers:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{array, makecell, multirow, graphicx}
 \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

 \begin{document}
     \begin{table}[ht]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|r|r|r|}
    \hline
    & \thead{Text} & \thead{Text} & \thead{Text} & \thead{Text} & \thead{text} \\     
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rota}} 
    & text          &&&&    \\     
    & text          &&&&    \\     
    & text          &&&&    \\     
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
     \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

*Note*: don't use table option `H` (in your case it not working since package, which provide it, is missing). Better is `ht` (here or if is not enough place for table/image,  on top of the next page).

[image]