# How do I make vertical text, and vertical lines in a table (with pgfplotstable)?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to format this table so that "presence of trait i" is printed vertically alongside a vertical rule left of the + and - sign, mimicking the horizontal "presence of trait j" in the following code.
Additionally, I would like to know how to keep the position of "presence of trait j" above column 2 and 3, when I remove the `\toprule`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{bmcart}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{presence of trait j} \\\cmidrule{2-3}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every column/.style={
  string type}
]{
Mode        -          +
+           a          b
-           c          d    
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot of result of current code]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: If you are willing to use a `tabular` instead of a `pgfplotstable`, then you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table.

Comment: I have updated the code to be a MWE.

Comment: is it possible to maintain the lay out that is generated by pgfplotstable?