# Problem with merge column in table

Tags: multicolumn

I have problem merging column in tex table. I'm posting my table in Word and the Tex code. ( I need these columns - 1 periodo, 2 periodo, 3 periodo.

Thank you!

[image: Table in Word]

Tex Code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable} %TABELA INVERTIRA
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{llX}
    \caption{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos em ordem cronológica de 1777 à 1990.}\label{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \centering
    \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    & & Continução Tabela \ref{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    1777-1778 & Priestley & Observou "gelo anômalo" se formando em temperaturas positivas, primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre (\ce{SO_2}). \\
    1810 & Davy & Descobriu hidratos de cloro, a partir de experimentos com de solução aquosa saturada com cloro, acima do ponto de solidificação da água.  \\
    1823 & Faraday & Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula \ce{Cl_2. 10 H_2O}. \\
    1878 & Cailletet & Descoberta de mistura de hidratos em sistemas de  alta pressões. \\
    1884 & le Chatelier & Observou que a curva de equilibrio do hidrato de cloro muda a inclinação em 273 K. \\
    1888 e 1890 & Villard & Determinou a existência de hidratos de etano (\ce{CH_4}), metano (\ce{C_2H_6}) e propano (\ce{C_3H_8}). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior. Sugeriu também que os hidratos eram cristais regulares.   \\
    1902 & de Forcrand & Utilizou a relação de Clausius-Clapeyron e estabeleceu condiçoes de temperatura de equilibrio para 15 hidratos. \\
    1934 e 1939 & Hammerschimidt & Identificou as principais causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural, sendo ocasionada por hidratos e estudou a utilização de inibidores. \\
    1946 & Deaton e Frost & Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano (\ce{CH_4}), etano (\ce{C_2H_6}) e propano (\ce{C_3H_8}).\\
    1951 e 1952 & Claussen, Pauling e Marsh & Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII. \\
    1954 & von Stackelberg e Müller & Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X, as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII. \\
    1965 e 1974 & Makogon & Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.\\
    1973 & Davidson & Produziu o material “Clatratos Hidratos” na Água: Um Tratado Abrangente. \\
    1980 & Kvenvolden e McMenamin & Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester e colaboradores & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1990 & Sloan & Produziu o material Clathrate Hidratos de Gases Naturais. \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: Probably related: [How to rotate text in multirow table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89115/134144)

Comment: Please make your code compilable (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))  so others can reproduce the output you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `sideways table` for a multipage table. The solution uses a `landscape` environment. The rotated titles on the left are obtained with a supplementary column and `multirow`. I added some vertical padding at the top and bottom of rows with the `cellspace` package.

```
    \documentclass[table]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{xltabular}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{multirow, cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}
    \addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
    \newcommand{\whitecell}{\cellcolor{white}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{landscape} %TABELA INVERTIRA
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
    \centering
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}clSl S{X}}
    \caption{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos em ordem cronológica de 1777 à 1990.}\label{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \whitecell & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
     & & & Continução Tabela \ref{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \whitecell & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
& 1777-1778 & Priestley & Observou "gelo anômalo" se formando em temperaturas positivas, primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre (\ce{SO_2}). \\
\whitecell & 1810 & Davy & Descobriu hidratos de cloro, a partir de experimentos com de solução aquosa saturada com cloro, acima do ponto de solidificação da água. \\
 & 1823 & Faraday & Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula \ce{Cl₂. 10 H₂O}. \\
\whitecell & 1878 & Cailletet & Descoberta de mistura de hidratos em sistemas de alta pressões. \\
 & 1884 & Le Chatelier & Observou que a curva de equilibrio do hidrato de cloro muda a inclinação em 273 K. \\
\whitecell & 1888 e 1890 & Villard & Determinou a existência de hidratos de etano (\ce{CH₄}), metano (\ce{C₂H₆}) e propano (\ce{C₃H₈}). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior. Sugeriu também que os hidratos eram cristais regulares. \\
 & 1902 & de Forcrand & Utilizou a relação de Clausius-Clapeyron e estabeleceu condiçoes de temperatura de equilibrio para 15 hidratos. \\
\multirow{-14.5}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries 1\textsuperscript{o} Periodo}} & 1934 e 1939 & Hammerschimidt & Identificou as principais causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural, sendo ocasionada por hidratos e estudou a utilização de inibidores. \\
\hline
 & 1946 & Deaton e Frost & Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano (\ce{CH₄}), etano (\ce{C₂H₆}) e propano (\ce{C₃H₈}).\\
\whitecell & 1951 e 1952 & Claussen, Pauling e Marsh & Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII. \\
\multirow{-4.5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries 2\textsuperscript{o} Periodo}} & 1954 & von Stackelberg e Müller & Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X, as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII. \\
 \hline
 \whitecell & 1965 e 1974 & Makogon & Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.\\
 & 1973 & Davidson & Produziu o material “Clatratos Hidratos” na Água: Um Tratado Abrangente. \\
\whitecell & 1980 & Kvenvolden e McMenamin & Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska. \\
 & 1987 & Ripmeester e colaboradores & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
\multirow{-6}{*}{\cellcolor{white}\rotatebox{90}{\bfseries 3 \textsuperscript{o} Periodo}} & 1990 & Sloan & Produziu o material Clathrate Hidratos de Gases Naturais. \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Yes, of course. 'Tis fixed. Thanks for pointing it!