# sidewaystable with long table - next page

Tags: tables, longtable, sidewaystable

I have a problem with my table. If I add more 4, 5 or 6 lines, cause error.

```
\begin{sidewaystable} %TABELA INVERTIRA
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{clX}
    \caption{Principais trabalhos referente à pesquisa sobre hidratos em ordem cronológica..}\label{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \centering
        \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    & & Continução Tabela \ref{tb:periodos} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Pesquisador} & \textbf{Contribuições} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    1777 / 1778     & Priestley  & Observou a formação de "gelo anômalo" se formando em temperaturas positivas, primeiro indicativo da formação de hidratos de dióxido de enxofre (\ce{SO_2}). \\
    1810        & Davy          & Descobriu hidratos de cloro, a partir de experimentos com de solução aquosa saturada com cloro, acima do ponto de solidificação da água (0 $^{\circ}$C).  \\
    1823        & Faraday       & Identificou as propriedades dos hidratos de gás cloro, com fórmula \ce{Cl_2. 10 H_2O}. \\
    1878        & Cailletet     & Descoberta de mistura de hidratos em sistemas de  alta pressão. \\
    1884        & le Chatelier  & Observou diferenças na curva de equilíbrio do hidrato de cloro. \\
    1888 / 1890 & Villard       & Determinou a existência de hidratos de metano (\ce{CH_4}), etano (\ce{C_2H_6}) e propano (\ce{C_3H_8}). E identificou o ponto quádruplo inferior. Sugeriu também que os hidratos eram cristais regulares.   \\
    1902        & de Forcrand       & Utilizou a relação de Clausius-Clapeyron e estabeleceu condições de temperatura de equilíbrio para 15 hidratos. \\
    1934 / 1939 & Hammerschimidt    & Identificou as principais causas do bloqueio de linhas de gás natural e estudou a utilização de inibidores. \\
    \hline
    1946 & Deaton e Frost & Realizaram experimentos de formação de hidratos a partir de componentes puros e misturas de metano (\ce{CH_4}), etano (\ce{C_2H_6}) e propano (\ce{C_3H_8}).\\
    1951 / 1952 & Claussen, Pauling e Marsh & Identificaram e nomearam duas diferentes estruturas cristalinas de hidratos como sI e sII. \\
    1954 & von Stackelberg e Müller & Confirmaram, através de difração de Raio X as estruturas cristalinas sI e sII. \\
    \hline
    1965 / 1974 & Makogon & Documentou a descoberta de reservas de hidratos de metano (\ce{CH_4}) na Sibéria, juntamente com a publicação do material Hidratos de Gás Natural.\\
    1980 & Kvenvolden e McMenamin & Descobriram a localização de hidratos em sedimentos rochosos no Alaska. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    1987 & Ripmeester et al. & Descobriram a existência da estrutura cristalina de hidratos sH. \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: `sidewaystable` is intened for one page table only. If you have longer table, than you need to use `landscape` environment defined in the `lscape` or `pdflscape` packages. To show you a solution, please provide small, self contained  document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: In [the answer to your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503975/134144), Bernard already showed you how to achieve a sideways multiple page spanning table using the `landscape` environment.