# Customising text in a table

Tags: tables, ieeetran, text

I am new to latex and in a pressing need to quickly design a fine confusion matrix (with text rotation) as in the attached screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure how the content can be customised in latex as in the shown table (Predicted column orientation, double-line horizontal line etc).

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

```
I would have love to use @Zarko's answer since I'm using `ieeetran` document class but I encountered an error:
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
```

with some options defined in the command appearing in the output:
[image]

Comment: you should most definitely add an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I suspect that you use `ieeetran` or similar document class. With employed `siunitx` package (for `S` columns), `booktabs` (for horizontal rules), `multirow` (for cell with vertical text), and `\rotating` and `makecell` (for rotate text in the first column) packages:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Confusion matrix for SVM using pooled features}
\label{tab:confusion}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\textbf{Predicted}}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\bfseries}l} *{6}{S[table-format=2.2]} }
    \toprule
    &   &   \mcc[6]{\textbf{Actual}}                            \\
    \cmidrule{3-8}
    &   & {\textbf{Bike}} & {\textbf{Car}}  & {\textbf{Walk}} 
        & {\textbf{Run}}  & {\textbf{Bus}}  & {\textbf{Precision}}\\ 
    \midrule
\multirow{5}{*}{\rothead{Predicted}} 
    & Bike   
        & 97.13         &  0.52         &  1.17         
        &  0.40         &  0.58         & 97.88     \\
 & Car  &  0.66         & 93.57         &  0.16
        &  0.13         &  3.06         & 95.88     \\
 & Walk &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & Run  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & Bus  &  0.92         &  2.42         &  0.40
        &  0.32         & 93.11         & 95.81     \\
    \midrule
 & Recall
        & 97.13         & 93.57         & 93.82    
        & 92.82         & 93.11         &           \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, actually I used `ieee` template.

Comment: Got an Error: ```The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}```

Comment: @super_ask, proposed MWE works out-of-box, if you have recent LaTeX installed. If not, It might help to add `\usepackage{xparse}` before `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` in preamble of MWE.

Comment: perfect, it works.

Comment: @super_ask, of course it works. It also has aligned numbers at decimal points, superior professional look-out  and simple, short code ;-).

Answer (score 2):

For double lines in tables you can use `hhline` package.

For rotation of text in tables `\rotatebox`. (explanation see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.9 cm}{\raggedright#1}}}
 
\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
%\caption{Table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\centering
\setlength\doublerulesep{0.8pt} % distance or the 2 lines in the double line
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
\specialrule{2pt}{1pt}{1pt} % thick line
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Actual}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{}}                       & \textbf{Bike} & \textbf{Car} & \textbf{Walk} & \textbf{Run} & \textbf{Bus} & \textbf{Precision} \\ \hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{\RotText{Predicted}}} 
 & \textbf{Bike}    & 97.13 & 0.52  & 1.1  7& 0.40  & 0.58  & 97.33 \\
 & \textbf{Car}     & 0.66  & 93.57 & 0.16  & 0.13  & 3.06  & 95.88 \\
 & \textbf{Walk}    & 0.29  & 0.08  & 93.59 & 0.92  & 0.29  & 97.68 \\
 & \textbf{Run}     & 0.37  & 0.05  & 0.93  & 92.82 & 0.20  & 98.36 \\
 & \textbf{Bus}     & 0.92  & 2.42  & 0.40  & 0.32  & 93.11 & 95.81 \\ \hline
 & \textbf{Recall}  & 97.13 & 93.57 & 93.59 & 92.82 & 93.11 &       \\ \hhline{========}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]