# Table (tabu) rotate text sideways (90 degrees)

Tags: tables, rotating

how can I rotate text in a `tabu` environment by 90 degrees? I export my tables from Excel using a plugin and it puts the text which should be rotated into `\begin{sideways} ... \end{sideways}` but Latex throws an error. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,DIV=12,a4paper,numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[L] X[L]}

\toprule 

AAAAAA & BBBBBB \\

% \begin{sideways}AAAAAA\end{sideways} & \begin{sideways}BBBBBB\end{sideways} \\

\end{tabu}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how about using a `rotatebox`?

Comment: You can try one of the methods outlined in [Rotated column titles in tabular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32683/rotated-column-titles-in-tabular) or in [How to write vertically in a cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41611/how-to-write-vertically-in-a-cell)

Comment: Cool thanks. I will try turn and rotate and see how far I get. Thanks for these two started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sideways` environment comes from the `rotating` package so the simplest thing to do is probably just add

```
\usepackage{rotating}
```

`rotating` package is mainly a wrapper around the standard `graphics` package rotation preserving the syntax of a pre-latex2e package, but if you already have generated that markup there is no harm in using it.

Comment: Yes, it was the package which was missing. Did not know that this function was included in an extra package. I finally just used sideways and it did its job so far :)